# Microsoft Access Report.Page uses data from next record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem with Access when a try to display a barcode on a Access Report. I use the Report.Page event to create the barcode as seen here:

```
Option Compare Database

Dim barcode As Control

Private Sub Report_Load()
    Set barcode = Me.Tekst15
    Debug.Print ("Geladen report: " + Trim([teldetail_tellijst] & "-" & [teldetail_nummer]))
End Sub

Private Sub Report_page()
    Debug.Print ("Print preview starten voor report: " + Trim([teldetail_tellijst] & "-" & [teldetail_nummer]) + "!")
    Debug.Print ("Loaded report: " + Me.Tekst0)
    Debug.Print ("Barcode to print: " + barcode)
    
    Result = Barcode_128(Me.Tekst15, Me)
    Me.Line (0, 0)-(Me.ScaleWidth, Me.ScaleHeight), , B
End Sub
```

But it uses the data from the next record.
As seen in this image: [report with barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veJxK.png)
if you scan the barcode it will read 10908-2 instead of the expected 10908-1

i tried changing the event where the barcode is generated but then the barcode will not show up. I also tried chaning the size of the record in the print preview to fit the A6 page it is printed on because if i load 2 reports on 1 A4 the barcode will only show up once(still with the data from the next record).

If you need more info to answer the question please let me know so i can provide the info.

Comment: Code should be posted into question as formatted text, not an image. Same for sample data. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I have a sample db that generates barcodes 128 and 39. Function to include in report is called from Print event of detail section. Did you try that event? Or even Format event?

Comment: @june7 when i use the print event the barcode does not display at all

Comment: Interesting, my code also has a line that sets boolean variable Result and makes me wonder if you have the same db. Calling from Print event definitely displays barcode. However, I don't have a reader to confirm the barcode correctly represents data.

Comment: Loaded a barcode reader on my phone and barcode translates to correct data. My code also does not have barcode public variable. Here's my source https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=33878

Comment: This belongs in the section's Format event. You need to open Print Preview, not Report View, to make this event run.

Comment: @Andre, image shows report in PrintPreview and OP says barcode will not show if code is used by Print event. Works for me with either Print or Format.